# Enterprise Library Validation Application Block validate object to relative object in hierarchy

Tags: c#, validation, hierarchical-data, enterprise-library-5, validation-application-bl

I have a kind of hierarchycal class, meaning that it contains collections of user defined objects. I want to be able to apply validation at child level but referencing some properties in the parent level. Is there a way to do this with the build in validator in Validation Application Block?
If not, I would really appriciate a generic example of such validator.

**UPDATE**

I thought giving a little example might help understanding the problem. So here it is:

```
public class Group
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public DateTime RegistrationDate {get;set;}    
    public List<Student> Students{ get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string BirthDate{ get; set; }
    public int GroupId {get;set;}
}
```

Now my problem is that I want to compute the `age` of a `person` at the registration date in the group and validate it.
This is only a trivial example as a have a little more complex scenarios than this.
What is the best way to validate it?